# Akka terminate message not being sent or routed somewhere else

Tags: akka, router, actor, terminate

I have a couple of actors that have multiple routers each for a specific type of actor.  I created a class RouteeTracker to (you guessed it) track which actor  belongs to each type of router.  This is to properly handle the terminated message from each type of actor.

```
public class RouteeTracker
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RouteeTracker.class);

    private Map<ActorRef, Router> routeeRouterMap = new HashMap<ActorRef, Router>();
    private Map<ActorRef, Class> routeeClassMap = new HashMap<ActorRef, Class>();
    private Map<Class, String> routeeDispatcherMap = new HashMap<Class, String>();

    Router register(Class actorClass, int actorPoolCount, UntypedActorContext untypedActorContext, RoutingLogic routingLogic, ApplicationContext applicationContext, String dispatcher)
    {
        List<Routee> routees;
        List<ActorRef> actors;

        routees = new ArrayList<>();
        actors = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < actorPoolCount; i++) {
            ActorRef r = untypedActorContext.actorOf(Props.create(actorClass, applicationContext).withDispatcher(dispatcher));
            logger.info("r={}",r.toString());
            actors.add(r);
            **untypedActorContext.watch(r);**
            routees.add(new ActorRefRoutee(r));
        }

        **Router router = new Router(routingLogic, routees);**
        routeeDispatcherMap.put(actorClass, dispatcher);

        for(ActorRef actor:actors)
        {
            routeeRouterMap.put(actor, router);
            routeeClassMap.put(actor, actorClass);
        }

        return router;
    }

    ActorRef handleTerminate(ActorRef actorRef, UntypedActorContext untypedActorContext)
    {
        logger.info("Entering RouteeTracker.handleTerminate({,{})",actorRef.toString(), untypedActorContext.toString());
        Router router = routeeRouterMap.get(actorRef);
        if(router == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("No router found for actorRef");

        Class actorClass = routeeClassMap.get(actorRef);
        String dispatcher = routeeDispatcherMap.get(actorClass);
        if(actorClass == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("No actorClass found for actorRef");

        **strong text**router.removeRoutee(actorRef);
        logger.info("####class:dispatcher {}:{}",actorClass.toString(),dispatcher);

        ActorRef r = untypedActorContext.actorOf(Props.create(actorClass).withDispatcher(dispatcher));
        untypedActorContext.watch(r);
        router.addRoutee(new ActorRefRoutee(r));

        //Cleanup
        routeeRouterMap.remove(actorRef);
        routeeClassMap.remove(actorRef);

        logger.info("Exiting RouteeTracker.handleTerminate({,{})",actorRef.toString(), untypedActorContext.toString());
        return r;
    }
}
```

I use this router in an actor like so:

```
public class Supervisor extends UntypedActor {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Supervisor.class);

    public static Props props(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        return Props.create(new Creator<Supervisor>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            public Supervisor create() throws Exception {
                return new Supervisor(applicationContext);
            }
        });
    }

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() { return applicationContext; }
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) { this.applicationContext = applicationContext; }


    private Router SIPRRouter;
    private Router SICRouter;
    private Router VFERouter;
    private RouteeTracker routeeTracker = new RouteeTracker();

    public Supervisor(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        sessionIdentifierGenerator = (SessionIdentifierGeneratorService) this.applicationContext.getBean("sessionIdentifierGeneratorServiceImpl");
     }

    @Override
    public void preStart() throws Exception {
        SIPRouter = routeeTracker.register(SIEProducer.class, 5, **getContext()**, new RoundRobinRoutingLogic(), applicationContext, "si-bio-d");
        SICRouter = routeeTracker.register(SIEConsumer.class, 5, **getContext()**, new RoundRobinRoutingLogic(), applicationContext, "si-bio-d");
        vfeRouter = routeeTracker.register(VFE.class, 10, **getContext()**, new RoundRobinRoutingLogic(), applicationContext, "fe-bio-d");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        if (message instanceof String) {

            String msg = (String) message;
            logger.debug("Supervisor::Received String message: {}", msg);

        } else if(message instanceof Terminated) {
            logger.info("handle terminated");
            routeeTracker.handleTerminate(((Terminated) message).actor(),getContext());
        } else {
            unhandled(message);
        }
        message = null;
    }

}
```

I've removed many messages that have nothing to do with handling the terminated  message for clarity.  The problem is that the actor never receives a terminated message. So my RouteeTracker.handleTerminated() method is never called. I can only assume that the message is never sent possibly because these child actors are not terminating, or the terminate message is not being sent.

I've based my router usage off of the Typesafe offical Akka-Java documentation.

I call untypedActor.watch(...) and add the newly created actor in the register method of routeeTracker.

I removed the actor from the router (and other data structures) in the terminate method of routeeTracker.

It does not appear that the child actor is being watched.

Thoughts anyone?

Comment: The answer is 42.